# Gatsby disable caching in production build

Tags: reactjs, gatsby

When you build a Gatsby application into production build, you will see the following in the console:

```
success Caching JavaScript and CSS webpack compilation - 25.915s
success Caching HTML renderer compilation - 14.491s
```

Gatsby caches some of the built files such that subsequence builds will be faster. The issue is, I'm deploying my project to a service that does not support caching. After the deployment, everything will be discarded. So it is meaningless to spend 20% of build time on caching.

Does anyone know how to disable caching while building production build?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways (as far as I know) to do this or at least you can try:

- In your `gatsby-node.js` using [`onPostBuild`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/config-files/gatsby-node/#onPostBuild) API call, where the cache management is set:

  ```
  exports.onPostBuild = async function ({ cache, graphql }, { query }) {
     const cacheKey = "some-key-name"
     const twentyFourHoursInMilliseconds = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 // 86400000
     let obj = await cache.get(cacheKey)

     if (!obj) {
       obj = { created: Date.now() }
       const data = await graphql(query)
       obj.data = data
     } else if (Date.now() > obj.lastChecked + twentyFourHoursInMilliseconds) {
       /* Reload after a day */
       const data = await graphql(query)
       obj.data = data
     }

     obj.lastChecked = Date.now()

     await cache.set(cacheKey, obj)

     /* Do something with data ... */
  }
  ```

  You can try returning/skipping the function before the cache acts.
- Trying using Gatsby flags:

  ```
  module.exports = {
     flags: {
       PRESERVE_WEBPACK_CACHE: false,
       PRESERVE_FILE_DOWNLOAD_CACHE: false
     },
     plugins: [...]
  }
  ```

  In this case, [`PRESERVE_WEBPACK_CACHE`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/28331%E2%80%8B) and [`PRESERVE_FILE_DOWNLOAD_CACHE`](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/discussions/28331) may be useful for you (umbrella issues linked).

Maybe you can start pulling the thread with those approaches.

Comment: The 2nd method definitely will not work, since those two are additional caches apart from the most basic build cache. In fact, they are disabled by default in Gatsby 3.

Comment: Yep, I thought that but maybe enlighten you in some magical approach. The `onPostBuild` is what Gatsby triggers in each build so, skipping the cache there should work, but apparently will need more tweak than it seems